# Should the Azure TableServiceContext be disposable?

Tags: azure-table-storage, tableservicescontext

I'm Starting out with Azure Tables in a new project.

I'm struck by the oddities with the TableServiceContext.

It appears to be simular to the LinqToSql context object, in that it tracks changes to objects etc.
But the TableServiceContext isn't disposable.

Should the TableServiceContext be disposable?

Answer (score 0):

Disposable is intended for when an object have access to a non managed resource. But it is common to use disposable to force certain cleanup/actions. I assume LinqToSql contexts may keep a connection to the database open which means it should be disposable so that connection can be closed. The TableServiceContext does not keep a connection open since it uses a REST protocol to do changes. The objects the context keep track of is just to be able to send the correct Etags for updates etc. So no, I don't think the TableServiceContext needs to be disposable.